# How to rewrite URLs with Javascript, whilst excluding some

Tags: javascript, url

I've created a script that rewrites outbound URLs on a page, excluding any URL that includes "http://www.mysite.com". Here is the script as it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function () {
         for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
              if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("http://www.mysite.com") == -1) {
                 document.links[i].href = 'http://www.mysite.com/redirect.php?' + document.links[i].href
              }
         }
    }
</script>
```

What I want to be able to do is list a number of URLs to exclude. What is the best way to do this?

Can I create an array of URLs to exclude and then make sure the script ignores any that are contained in that array?

If so, how would I construct an if statement for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean just to test if some value(url in this case) is contained in your prepared array?